# Average Iterating through list

Tags: python, excel

I'm new to Python coming from excel. I want average for a list but for each new item.  For a list:

```
x = [-3.2, 2.7, -8.5, -1.4]
```

I've tried:

```
avg = sum(col)/len(col)
```

And that gives a result of -2.6, which is the whole column divided by whole count. I want it to return the average at each iteration. I've tried to use a for loop:

```
def avg2(x):
    ttl = 0
    for i in x:
        ttl += i
        res = ttl / len(x)
    return res
```

Same result, whole sum / whole column. Its going through whole list, not the totals at each value. As a reference the excel formula would be (for numbers in column A):

```
=AVERAGE(A$1:A4)
```

When you drag the formula down to A5, the result will be for everything at that iteration.

Perhaps using enumerate or loop within a loop?

Comment: Do you mean for element 2 , you need the average till that?

Comment: I try to understand what you mean by an average for each new item, but I don't get it. Could you give a numerical example.

Comment: What do you mean by average here?

Comment: suppose i have 4 numbers in list and average for each number will be sum of numbers till that offset divided by offset or sum of numbers till that offset divided by the length of list.

Comment: so you want to compute the average on a smaller `list`?

Comment: In excel, lets say the numbers above are in cells A1 to A4. If I put the excel function "=AVERAGE(A$1:A1)" in B1, the numbers in B1 to B4 will read: -3.2, -0.25, -3, -2.6

Comment: Why don't you store the results in a list and then return it all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not saving your result anywhere during your loop. you are only returning it at the end so that's why you are getting these results:

```
def avg2(x):
    res = []
    total = 0
    for i in x:
        total += i
        res.append(total / len(x))
    return res
```

Will result in:

```
>>> x = [-3.2, 2.7, -8.5, -1.4]
>>> avg2(x)
[-0.8, -0.125, -2.25, -2.6]
```

Note that this averages the `total` over the length of the entire list not the number of values that have been averaged so far. For example when it is averaging `-0.125` it's doing `-0.925 / 4` not `-0.925/ 2`. To achieve that you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and it's optional `start` parameter to avoid division by 0:

```
def avg2(x):
    res = []
    total = 0
    for idx, i in enumerate(x, 1):
        total += i
        res.append(total / idx)
    return res
```

Comment: Thank you IanAuld for the solution and the steps you used to get there.

Answer (score 3):

Your average function:

```
def avg(lst): return sum(lst)/len(lst)
```

Basically you want to apply `avg()` to slices of `x`. Just for clarity, slices of `x` are:

```
>>> x[:1]
[-3.2]
>>> x[:2]
[-3.2, 2.7]
>>> x[:3]
[-3.2, 2.7, -8.5]
```

Apply it to slices of `x`, using a list comprehension:

```
>>> [avg(x[:i]) for i in range(1,len(x)+1)]
[-3.2, -0.25, -3.0, -2.6]
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution mescalinum. I prefer to use IanAuld's answer but this is great too.