# What to do for this loop? Write code that assigns the average of the numbers from 1 to n (where n is a positive integer value) to the variable avg

Tags: python

Write code that assigns the average of the numbers from 1 to n (where n is a positive integer value) to the variable avg. The answer is specifically asking for a for loop but idk how to start it off. Does it have to be a for x in range... or is it something else. plz help I'm just starting my first programming class and idk what to do.

I tried to enter avg = (1+n)/2 but its not excepting that and with the lesson being on for loops I'd assume I would need to make a for loop.

Comment: Start with understanding how for loops work (ex. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) and researching existing posts about getting the average at each iteration (ex. https://stackoverflow.com/q/31120372/2745495).

Comment: Also, if you have any code, please post it in future questions as this helps others understand what you are trying to acheive, and what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

I think this solves your problem, although you should try to understand what is going on so you may apply your learning in the future.

Here's what I wrote:

```py
n=int(input("Enter number: "))
avg=sum([x for x in range(1,n+1)])/len(range(1,n+1))
print(avg)
```

This takes input in line 1, sums all the numbers between 1 and `n` in line 2, and prints out the value in line 3.

To break it down: line 1 takes input. the `int` statement makes it into a number rather than a string, which is what normally comes out of an input.

Line 2:
This line is where the for loop comes in. I have compacted mine into a generator statement, but thats not absolutely necessary. First, the generator statement puts all the numbers 1 to `n` into a list.  It then sums up all of the variables in the list, and assigns it to `avg`.

This is what it would look like uncompacted:

```py
list_var=[]
for x in range(0,n+1): # Range returns numbers between the min and max, but not including the max. Therefore, put a +1 afterwards to ensure it includes the max.
  list_var.append(x) # put the variable in the list
sum_of=sum(list_var) #sum returns the sum of all the items in the list.
avg=sum_of/len(range(1,n+1) #avg is the average (1-n)/length (which is the length of the range)
```

Finally, the print statement logs it to the console.

```py
print(avg)
```

Ta-da

Answer (score 0):

That python explanation helped clear things up more than my chapter. Ty!

```
total = 0
for i in range (1,n+1):
total+=i
avg = float(total)/n
```